# Self Join multiple rows in sql and create new columns

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to join multiple rows having same column DN value and creating view by showing them in multiple columns.

Table is:

| OrderID | DN | Attributecode | Attributevalue | Itemcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 150000565101091 | 14768703 | contractId | 100000022 | Silver_Bundle |
| 150000565101091 | 14768703 | activationDateInherited | 11-JAN-21 | Silver_Bundle |
| 150000565101091 | 14768703 | contractExpiryDate | 11-APR-21 | Silver_Bundle |

I was able to convert contractExpiryDate row to column using below query:

```
SELECT
    oeinfo.ORDERID,
    oeinfo.itemcode, oeinfo.dn, oeinfo.version, 
    TO_DATE(oeinfo.CONTRACTEXPIRYDATE,'dd-MON-YY HH24:mi:ss') "CONTRACTEXPIRYDATE", oeinfo.LASTUPDATEDDATE
FROM
    (SELECT
         coe.ORDERID, coe.ordertype, coe.channel, coe.MSISDN,ACCOUNTID, coe.CUSTOMERID,
         coe.ItemCode, coe.DN, coe.version, attributevalue CONTRACTEXPIRYDATE,
         coe.updateddate LASTUPDATEDDATE
     FROM 
         CWT_OM_ORDEREVENTS COE 
     WHERE
         coe.validfromdate > SYSDATE - 2 
         AND coe.attributecode = 'contractExpiryDate') "OEINFO" 
WHERE
    version = 1;
```

Result is :

| OrderID | DN | CONTRACTEXPDATE | Itemcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 150000565101091 | 14768703 | 11-APR-21 | Silver_Bundle |

How can I convert rows (activationDateInherited and contract Id) into columns having the same DN values?

Output should look like:

| OrderID | DN | CONTRACTEXPDATE | ACTIVATIONDATE | CONTRACTID | Itemcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 150000565101091 | 14768703 | 11-APR-21 | 11-JAN-21 | 100000022 | Silver_Bundle |

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
Select orderid, dn, 
       Max(case when atrributecode = 'contractId' then attributevalue end) as contractId,
      Max(case when atrributecode = 'activationDateInherited' then attributevalue end) as activationDateInherited,
      Max(case when atrributecode = 'contractExpiryDate' then attributevalue end) as contractExpiryDate,
       Itemcode
  From t
Group by orderid, dn, itemcode
```

Comment: Thank you. But requirement is that the DN column value should be same for contractId, activationDateInherited, contractExpiryDate rows. above query is returning the rows for all Dn values

Comment: I did not get it. It should return 1 row per DN column and it is according to sample data and expected ouput.

Comment: For multiple DN, query will give one record per combination of `orderid, dn, itemcode` and if you have some other requirement then you must give it straight ahead in the question.

Comment: Actually, DN can be multiple like:

|OrderID                 |   DN        |Attributecode               |Attributevalue| Itemcode     |
|-------------------------|-------------|-------------------------------|------------------ |------------------|
|150000565101091|14768703|contractId                     |100000022    |Silver_Bundle|
|150000565101091|14768703|activationDateInherited|11-JAN-21     |Silver_Bundle|
|150000565101091|14768703|contractExpiryDate 1    |1-APR-21      |Silver_Bundle|
|150000565101091|14768722|activationDateInherited|11-JAN-21     |Silver_Bundle|

Comment: In given data, Query will return two records for DN `14768722` and `14768703`

Comment: Actually, if you see the query that I wrote in the question, the inner part of the query is returning the DN for contractExpiryDate. I need to take that DN and use it to get the values of activationDateInherited & contractId if they have the same DN as of  contractExpiryDate.

Comment: @isha . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  You can run it on the sample data and see that.  If you have a *different* question, then accept this answer and ask a new question with more appropriate sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot function

```
select * from <table>
pivot
(max(attributevalue)
for attribute_code in ('contractId','activationDateInherited','contractExpiryDate')) order by DN;
```

Comment: Thank you. But requirement is that the DN column value should be same for contractId, activationDateInherited, contractExpiryDate rows. above query is returning the rows for all Dn values.

Comment: Sorry i did not get your question. Above query will give one row for same DN as shown in sample data, if there is different DN , it will give different rows. Can you please explain what is required with sample data